# Is there any support with a NetGear WNA3100 USB Adapter in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: netgear

Has there been any changes or updates or additions to Ubuntu 12.10's to pick up a `NetGear WNA3100 USB Adapter`? Or software updates? Or what can I do to get it to work in the latest Ubuntu 12.10?

Please, assist.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no native driver on the near horizon. It can however, work with ndiswrapper. See here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1965989  and here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946875

The exact process depends on your device details:     lsusb

It will be tricky in a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Best resource i found was here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11199585

Comment: Can you summarize that resource? It's either a dead link or it requires an account on that site. (Otherwise, this would be better as a comment than an answer.)